# Превышение максимального размера поля @Size(max = 36) не выбрасывает сообщений об ошибке?

Tags: spring, jaxb, bean-validation

Приложение на spring-rest+jaxb
Для входящих xml есть модели, например

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @Size(max = 36)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 1024)
    @XmlElement(name = "surnane", required = true)
    private String surname;

    @Size(max = 6)
    @XmlElement(name = "type", required = true)
    private String type;
}
```

Соответственно посылаю xml в контроллер заведомо невалидный, где поле тип больше 6 символов.

```
<User>
    <name>Alex</name>
    <surname>Tarantino</surname>
    <type>FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</type>
</User>
```

Но нет никакого сообщения об ошибке?
В jaxb длину полей нужно ограничивать каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Как делаете валидацию?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ожидал, что будет сразу выпадать ошибка без доп. действия от меня. Судя по Вашему вопросу я не прав.

Comment: Что-то должно делать валидацию. Это может быть ваш код, может быть явно или неявно заданный вилидатор в контексте Spring, валидатор Hibernate или что-то ещё. Для каждого случая свои нюансы.